# If a function has no critical points, then its zero set has no interior points

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f  \in  C^1$ in the open set $\Omega$ and have no critical points there. Let $E$ be the set where $f=0$. Show that $E$ has no interior points.

The back of the book says "If $f$ is constant on an open set then $Df=0$ there."  I see this would contradict the fact that there are no critical points in $\Omega$. But I do not understand how "constant on an open set" relates to interior points.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your post to share your thoughts on the problem, and explain what you've tried. People are happy to help, but generally only if you've shown some effort in solving the problem yourself, and have given some context to let us know what your thoughts are.

Comment: The back of the book says "If f is constant on an open set then Df=0 there." I do not understand how this deals with interior points. This seems to contradict the fact that $\Omega$ has no critical points.

Comment: Precisely. If the level set $f=0$ has an interior point $p$, then you will conclude that $Df(p)=0$.

Comment: Does the set $\Omega$ have interior points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problems appear in and old test of multivariable calculus. 
Suppose the contrary. Let $a\in E$ an interior point. Then there is $\delta>0$ such that $$B_{\delta}(a)\subseteq E$$ and $$B_{\delta}(a)\subseteq \Omega$$ because is an open. Then for all $p\in B_{\delta}(a)$ we have $f(p)=0$. Let $U=B_{\delta}(a)$ a 'hood of $a$, then because $f\in C^1$ we have $$Df=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\cdots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_p }\right)$$ but each partial derivate vanishes at $U$ (in at least one point say $p$). So $$Df(p)=0$$. A contradicction.